# selenium + phantomJS web elements internal exceptions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I am performing a web page scrape using `jrel 8.0_144`, `selenium 3.5.0` and `phantomJS driver 2.1.1`.

For an input element with an id of "quantity", the code:

```
public boolean enterQuantity (WebDriver driver, String id, int qty)
{
    boolean result = false;
    long delay = 30000;   // should be ample!
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait (driver, delay);
        wait.until (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.id (id)));

        WebElement we = driver.findElement (By.id (id));

        WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait (driver, delay);
        wait2.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf (we));

        we.sendKeys (Integer.toString (qty));
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Exception : " + e.getMessage ());
    }
    return result;
}
```

produces something like:

```
|.enterQuantity : we = [[PhantomJSDriver: phantomjs on XP (b2ff4fa0-7e9a-11e8-bbd0-d99690573e94)] -> id: quantity]
|.waitUntilVisible : we = [[PhantomJSDriver: phantomjs on XP (b2ff4fa0-7e9a-11e8-bbd0-d99690573e94)] -> id: quantity]
|.waitUntilVisible : Exception : Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[PhantomJSDriver: phantomjs on XP (b2ff4fa0-7e9a-11e8-bbd0-d99690573e94)] -> id: quantity] (tried for 25 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.5.0', revision: '8def36e068', time: '2017-08-10T23:00:22.093Z'
System info: host: 'XYZ', ip: '192.168.0.123', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=false, databaseEnabled=false, version=2.1.1, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy=Proxy(direct), nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, driverVersion=1.2.0, locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false, browserName=phantomjs, takesScreenshot=true, driverName=ghostdriver, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: b2ff4fa0-7e9a-11e8-bbd0-d99690573e94
| NB we.sendKeys () executed at this point
|.enterQuantity : Exception web element "quantity" not visible
```

The first observation is that whatever interrupt is generated by the wait for visibility of the `WebElement` does not reach the `catch (Exception e)` statement in the code.

This code works flawlessly using an `Internet Explorer driver`; but a headless driver is required by the application.

Any ideas?

---

### Update:

Implementing @cruisepandey's solution here is the error stack trace:

From phantomjsdriver.log:

```
[ERROR - 2018-07-03T11:28:18.791Z] Session [68a4d9c0-7eb3-11e8-8639-3bb49fd74d3e] - page.onError - msg: Error fetching the availability or geometry data 
[ERROR - 2018-07-03T11:28:18.791Z] Session [68a4d9c0-7eb3-11e8-8639-3bb49fd74d3e] - page.onError - stack: (anonymous function) ([web page address redacted]) 
[ERROR - 2018-07-03T11:28:19.075Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1530617299040
```

Comment: share the HTML code in text format.

Comment: did you check it manually, as how long does it take to display element with id `quantity`, is it visible in the browser window or you need to scroll to bottom, as end to end testing is mimicking the manual flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
public boolean enterQuantity (WebDriver driver, String id, int qty)
{
    boolean result = false;
    long delay = 30000;   // should be ample!
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, delay);
        WebElement  we = wait.until (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.id(id)));

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(we));
        we.sendKeys(Integer.toString(qty));
        result = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println ("Exception : " + e.getMessage ());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: comment too long

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elementToBeClickable` it checks if element is enabled and visible:

```
public boolean enterQuantity (WebDriver driver, String id, int qty)
{
    boolean result = false;
    long delay = 30000;   // should be ample!
    try
    {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, delay);
    wait.until (ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id (id)));

    WebElement we = driver.findElement (By.id (id));
    we.click(); // click on element before send keys
    we.sendKeys (Integer.toString (qty));
    result = true;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println ("Exception : " + e.getMessage ());
}
return result;
}
```